# recursive processing list and sublist of list gives a type mismatch

Tags: list, recursion, f#

I try to put a branching diagram into lists and sublists
layout is

- msg01
- msg02

  - msg03
  - msg04
- msg05

And i want to walk the branching diagram top -> bottom going into each branch
but it fails with

> Error Type mismatch. Expecting a     `('a * 'b list) list`     but given a     `'b list`     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying '`'a`' and '`'b * 'a list`'

Can anybody gives me some ideas what could fix this?

```
open System

let msgDiagram1 = [ ("msg03",[]); ("msg04",[]) ]
let msgDiagram = [ ("msg01", []); ("msg02", msgDiagram1); ("msg05",[]) ]      

let listToString lst =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | []    -> acc
        | x::xs -> let node = x
                   let sublst = snd(node)                      
                   if not ( sublst = List.empty ) then                        
                        loop "" sublst
                   else 
                        loop (acc + (string x)) xs

    loop "" lst

printfn "%A" (listToString msgDiagram)
```

Comment: As @pad said below, you really want to structure this as a tree--will make things vastly simpler for you.  See this blog posting <http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/catamorphisms-part-two/> for some great ideas on how to structure tree data in F# and how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `msgDiagram1` and `msgDiagram` have different types, you cannot use the same `loop` function on them. One quick fix is to process differently on `msgDiagram1`:

```
let listToString lst =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | (lbl, diag)::xs ->
            match diag with
            | [] -> loop (acc + string lbl + "\n") xs
            | _ ->
                let s = diag |> List.map (fun (label, _) -> "..." + label) 
                             |> String.concat "\n"
                loop (acc + string lbl + "\n" + s + "\n") xs
    loop "" lst
```

You chose a wrong data structure for the job; therefore, you cannot represent more than 2 levels of diagrams and these levels are forced to have different types. The right tool to use here is recursive tree data structure:

```
type Diagram = Branch of string * Diagram list
```

Now above values can be defined using the same type `Diagram list`:

```
let msgDiagram1 = [ Branch ("msg03",[]); Branch ("msg04", []) ]
let msgDiagram = [ Branch ("msg01", []); Branch ("msg02", msgDiagram1); 
                   Branch ("msg05", []) ]
```

and `listToString` can be rewritten to process `Diagram list` recursively in one batch.